# Identify Sequence and Provide 4th Integer

Tags: c#, numbers, sequence

I was tasked to solve this challenge on a programming exam, but I'm not sure that I have properly solved it. I am inquisitive about what really is the solution to this task:

**Make an application that will tell the user to input 3 numbers, identify the sequence, and provide the 4th integer. It should prompt if no relations is found**

*Note: Possible operators may include addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponent, and modulo division.*

Sample Output:

2, 4, 6, **8**

10, 9, 7, **4**

1, 4, 9, **16**

1, 1, 2, **6**

120, 120, 60, **20**

**Here is my solution so far:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace TestQuestionnaire
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var numbers = new int[3];
            string answer;
            bool exit = false;

            
            while (!exit)
            {
                // Loop for 5 times
                for (int n = 0; n <= 5; n++)
                {
                    // User Input
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 3 Numbers.");
                    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var error = false;

                        while (!error)
                        {
                            Console.Write("Enter Number: ");
                            error = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numbers[i]);
                            if (!error) Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number! Enter a Valid Number and Try Again. ");
                        }
                    }
                    NextNumber(numbers);
                }

                // Prompt for exit
                Console.WriteLine("Finished! Try Again? Y/N");
                answer = Console.ReadLine()?.ToUpper();
                if (answer == "N")
                {
                    exit = true;
                }

            }

           
        }

        private static void NextNumber(int[] numbers)
        {
            int next = 0;
            int interval_one = 0;
            int interval_two = 0;

            // determine if first two number is descending, ascending or equal (addition and subtraction)
            if (numbers[0] < numbers[1])
            {
                interval_one = (numbers[1] - numbers[0]);

                if (numbers[1] > numbers[2])
                {
                    interval_two = (numbers[1] - numbers[2]);
                }
                else
                {
                    interval_two = (numbers[2] - numbers[1]);
                }

                //determine if constant interval (eg, 2,4,6,8 or 1,2,3,4) otherwise evaluate more
                if (interval_one == interval_two)
                {
                    next = numbers[2] + interval_two;
                }
                else
                {
                    next = numbers[2] + interval_two + (interval_two - interval_one);
                }
            }
            else if (numbers[0] > numbers[1])
            {
                interval_one = numbers[0] - numbers[1];

                if (numbers[1] > numbers[2])
                {
                    interval_two = (numbers[1] - numbers[2]);
                }
                else
                {
                    interval_two = (numbers[2] - numbers[1]);
                }

                if (interval_one == interval_two)
                {
                    next = numbers[2] - interval_two;
                }
                else
                {
                    next = numbers[2] - interval_two + (interval_one - interval_two);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (numbers[0]/1 == numbers[1] && numbers[1]/2 == numbers [2])
                {
                    next = numbers[2] / 3;
                }
                else if (numbers[0] * 1 == numbers[1] && numbers[1]*2 == numbers[2])
                {
                    next = numbers[2] * 3;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Predicted 4th Number: {0}", next);

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The main problem I can see with this question is **not** that lack of code, or the fact that you have no idea how to achieve it, but that you tagged 2 completely different languages

Comment: My bad. I have written this question on my phone. Gonna edit it with some code later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have an Idea but I hope this can help

> using +

```
2 4 6 8
 2 2 2
```

```
10 9 7 4
  1 2 3
   1 1
```

```
1 4 9 16
 3 5 7
  2 2
```

> diffrent way(*)

```
1 1 2 6
 1 2 3# now +
  1 1
```

> use '/'

```
120 120 60 20
   1   2  3# use +
     1   1
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope you'll pay it forward.

Comment: This sometimes needs more than 3 interger

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to recognize all sequences of numbers, as each is defined by a very different relation. You would essentially have to hardcode each case as listed in the examples. And even then, there is no one correct answer. For your fourth example, I could see the sequence `1 1 2 2 3 3...` being just as reasonable as `1 1 2 6...`. In fact, the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences finds 35,000 results for the the sequence `1 1 2` (see https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C1%2C2&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Putting that aside though, I'll give some pseudocode for the examples (I'm assuming, given that you are fine with Python or C#, that the language itself is not particularly important, and that you probably already know how to do the "getting input" and "returning results" portions.).

1. if the difference between each number is equal, add that difference to the last number and return it
2. if the difference between each number is the sequence `1 2 3...`, return the last number plus the next difference (4 in this case)
3. If the numbers are the squares, return the next square (16 in this case)
4. If each number divided by the previous number is the sequence `1 2 3`, return 4 * the last number
5. If each number divided by the next number is the sequence `1 2 3`, return the last number divided by 4.

Of course, a more robust solution would account for negative sequences, or those that bounce back and forth between positive and negative. But again, it is an underdetermined problem.